How can I learn about Zero-Knowledge Proof from scratch in 2024? Roadmap?
Looking for resources that explain zkp, zk-snark, zk-stark in depth. I am new into cryptography and want to understand it from scratch, theoretically and implementation wise. This is specifically for an identification project.
I understand this space moves quite fast so I'm also looking for newer resources to understand the latest advancements as-well in 2024.
Plus points if someone can give me a roadmap into understanding this overall topic in depth for a newbie. Please don't go light on the references as i'm ready to go through this rabbit hole.
Books, articles, videos the more the merrier!!

Impossible to ansswer without you stating your background knowledge, programming, math, algorithms.

Currently doing masters in ai/ml so bit of programming background & maths too.

My own ordered experience:

The Princeton Companion to Mathematics – Princeton University Press - Timothy Gowers & others (section IV.20 “Computational Complexity”)
to understand wich CS foundations lay the basement for cryptography

Foundation of Cryptography – Cambridge University Press - Oded Goldreich (Volume I, chapters 1 and 4; all companion web pages stuff; errata)
foundational book on ZKPs, of course not up-to-date, but really useful to understand gradually (I have cheat-sheeted some parts here: https://www.bybaro.it/tss/ZKbasicsCheatsheet20220621.pdf , with many references on the bottom, I underline Geoﬀroy Couteau's ones for newbies, and Matthew Green's blog for unleashed posts about applied crypto, also on ZKPs)

Zero Knowledge Proofs Spring 2023 MOOC by Berkeley: not for the faint of heart ones but a really comprehensive (clever)undergraduate-level examination of this topics: in 2003 it has been offered as free semestral course with chat board on Discord (sometimes attended by teachers as well) and NFT certification in the end for the ones who succeeded keeping the pace; maybe they will repeat the experience (??), anyway everything from 2003 edition is still online

I have recently found https://www.rareskills.io/zk-book: not checked yet, but after a quick look I guess I will use it to brush up concept from ZK MOOC, and as support for a couple of ZK MOOC lessons harder than average ones for me

Opinionated :-) keywords about very recent advancements I know: Lasso, Jolts by Justin Thaler. And actually edge research on the field seems concentrated around A16z, an USA venture-capital firm by Andreessen and Horowitz, interesting seminars on their crypto youttube channel: https://www.youtube.com/@a16zcrypto


Please keep in mind it's a very demanding path, needing time to gradually learn all the stuff
m2c :-)
